# Crop Image UWP не правильно обрезает изображение

Tags: uwp

Доброго времени суток. 
Нужно обрезать изображение по выбранной области делаю следующим образом

```
double scale = 1;

if (double.IsNaN(scale) || double.IsInfinity(scale))
{
    scale = 1;
}

double sourceImageWidthScale = Container.ActualWidth / WB_CapturedImage.PixelWidth;
double sourceImageHeightScale = Container.ActualHeight / WB_CapturedImage.PixelHeight;

Size previewImageSize = new Size(
    rect.Width / sourceImageWidthScale,
    rect.Height / sourceImageHeightScale);

double previewImageScale = 1;

if (previewImageSize.Width <= Container.ActualWidth &&
    previewImageSize.Height <= Container.ActualHeight)
{
    previewImageScale = Math.Max(Container.ActualWidth / previewImageSize.Width,
     Container.ActualHeight / previewImageSize.Height);
}

// Convert start point and size to integer. 
uint startPointX = (uint)Math.Floor(Point3.Position.X / sourceImageWidthScale * previewImageScale);
uint startPointY = (uint)Math.Floor(Point3.Position.Y / sourceImageWidthScale * previewImageScale);
uint height = (uint)Math.Floor(previewImageSize.Height * previewImageScale);
uint width = (uint)Math.Floor(previewImageSize.Width * previewImageScale);


using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await storgae.OpenReadAsync())
{

    // Create a decoder from the stream. With the decoder, we can get  
    // the properties of the image. 
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

    // The scaledSize of original image. 

    uint scaledWidth = (uint)Math.Floor(decoder.PixelWidth * previewImageScale);
    uint scaledHeight = (uint)Math.Floor(decoder.PixelHeight * previewImageScale);

    // Refine the start point and the size.  
    if (startPointX + width > scaledWidth)
    {
        startPointX = scaledWidth - width;
    }

    if (startPointY + height > scaledHeight)
    {
        startPointY = scaledHeight - height;
    }


    // Create cropping BitmapTransform and define the bounds. 
    BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform();
    BitmapBounds bounds = new BitmapBounds();
    bounds.X = startPointX;
    bounds.Y = startPointY;
    bounds.Height = height;
    bounds.Width = width;
    transform.Bounds = bounds;


    transform.ScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
    transform.ScaledHeight = scaledHeight;

    // Get the cropped pixels within the bounds of transform. 
    PixelDataProvider pix = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
        transform,
        ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
        ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
    byte[] pixels = pix.DetachPixelData();


    // Stream the bytes into a WriteableBitmap 
    WriteableBitmap cropBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
    Stream pixStream = cropBmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    pixStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)(width * height * 4));

   Target.Source = cropBmp;
    rect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Где

```
StorageFile storgae;
WriteableBitmap WB_CapturedImage;
Canvas Container = new Canvas();
```

Правильно обрезаю квадратные картинки (300х300, 600х600..). Прямоугольные изображение вырезаю смещённую область. Подскажите что не то сделал?